# Access data from JSON in SQL Server 2104

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have some data in JSON format and I want to access comma-separated user id  from that JSON data in SQL Server 2014. And after I want to store this separated data into table or table variable.

JSON:

```
{
   "PK_ID":0,
   "Group_Id":39,
   "Group_Name":null,
   "Admin_User_Id":0,
   "DisplayName":null,
   "Sms":true,
   "Email":false,
   "WhatsApp":false,
   "UpdatedBy":28,
   "CreatedBy":28,
   "users":[
      {"UserID":"5"},
      {"UserID":"7"},
      {"UserID":"22"},
      {"UserID":"23"},
      {"UserID":"24"},
      {"UserID":"25"},
      {"UserID":"33"},
      {"UserID":"45"},
      {"UserID":"46"},
      {"UserID":"47"}
   ],
   "MailOfficial":null,
   "CC":null,
   "BCC":null,
   "EmailSubject":null,
   "EmailContent":null,
   "MessageText":null,
   "WhatsAppText":null,
   "SpName":null,
   "MobileNo":null,
   "TypeOfReport":null
}
```

Comment: If you can use SQL Server 2016+ with built-in JSON support, you simply need this statement: `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.users') WITH (UserID nvarchar(2) '$.UserID')`.

Comment: Time is up to upgrade your SQL Server. Even SQL Server 2016 Falling Out of Mainstream Support this month. https://glennsqlperformance.com/2021/06/14/sql-server-2016-falling-out-of-mainstream-support/